# SVG Text Trace по-другому отображается на устройствах iOS

Tags: javascript, css, ios, svg

Я использую анимацию трассировки SVG с помощью CSS, меняя значения `stroke-dasdoffset` с помощью анимации ключевых кадров.

При тестировании моих проектов на устройствах iOS (iPad / iPhone) кажется, что `stroke-dasdoffset` / массив рассчитывается по-другому, до такой степени, что получается совершенно другая анимация.

Я думал, что причиной была моя реализация, но после тестирования следующих Codepens в Chrome / Safari / Firefox, похоже, что это происходит в каждом сценарии, и анимация контура различается на разных устройствах.

- https://codepen.io/csbatista/pen/EgxQgx
- https://codepen.io/MilloEscobar/pen/eNVaed

```
<svg version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
class=" ebw-nuwaru-page-title-svg" viewbox="0 0 250 90">
 <text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="60" 
      class="title-text text-stroke" clip-path="url(#text1)">Newfire
 </text>
 <defs> <clipPath id="text1"> 
    <text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="60" class="title-text">Newfire</text> </clipPath>
 </defs> 
</svg>
```

Есть ли ошибки в части CSS, которые  искажают работу на устройствах iOS?
Я хотел бы понять, что происходит, и не является ли это ограничением или просто ошибкой программирования.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG Text Trace rendered differently on iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69696541/7394871) от участника  [@TheGoldenD0nut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10287313/thegoldend0nut).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69696541/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обдумайте решение при котором у текста каждая буква преобразована в отдельный векторный объект

Такое преобразование даст  гарантию кроссбраузерности решения.

Для этого в векторном редакторе, например Inkscape:

1. Установите нужный вам размер документа
2. Выберете  нужный шрифт, его размер
3. Введите необходимый текст
4. Выберете в верхнем меню пункт:  контур / оконтурить объект  <kbd>Shift + Ctrl + C</kbd>
5. Сохраните файл в формате *.svg
6. При необходимости делается оптимизация кода с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Далее добавляются стили CSS и аниимация stroke-dashoffset

```css
.text-line {
fill:none;
stroke:#2A4A73;
stroke-width:2;
 stroke-dasharray: 572;
  stroke-dashoffset: 572;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards, filling 4s ease-in 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes filling {
  from{
    fill: #2A4A73;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    fill: #2A4A73;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 1000 100">
  <g aria-label="Hell0 World!" style="line-height:13px;-inkscape-font-specification:'Georgia Bold'" id="text819" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="700" font-stretch="normal" font-size="100" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none">
    <path class="text-line" id="H"  d="M288 90h-36v-4h4l3-1 2-2 1-3V57h-29v23l1 3 2 2h3l4 1v4h-36v-4h3l4-1 2-2 1-3V33l-1-3-2-2-4-1h-3v-4h36v4h-3l-4 1-2 2-1 3v20h29V33l-1-3-2-2-3-1h-4v-4h36v4h-3l-4 1-2 2-1 3v47l1 3 2 2 4 1h3z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="E" d="m345 78-4 5-6 5-6 2-7 1q-7 0-12-2l-9-5-5-8-1-10q0-5 2-9 1-4 5-8l8-5q5-2 11-2l10 1q5 2 7 5 3 2 4 6l1 8v3h-31q0 9 3 14 4 5 12 5 5 0 8-2 4-2 6-6zm-18-17-1-6-1-5q0-2-2-3l-3-1q-4 0-6 3-2 4-2 12z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="L_1" d="M378 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V26l-2-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z"/>
    <path class="text-line" id="L_2"  d="M411 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V26l-2-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="O_1" d="M468 46q4 4 5 9 2 4 2 9 0 7-2 12l-6 8-9 5q-5 2-12 2t-12-2q-6-2-9-6-4-3-6-8t-2-11l2-10 5-8q4-4 10-6 5-2 12-2 8 0 13 2t9 6zm-13 35 2-7V56l-2-8q-1-3-4-4-2-2-5-2t-5 2l-4 4-1 7-1 9v9l2 7q1 3 4 5 2 2 5 2t5-2q3-1 4-4z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="W" d="m614 27-3 1-3 1-3 2-1 4-8 23-12 32h-9l-18-49-15 49h-10l-12-35-7-20-2-4-3-2-2-2h-4v-4h36v4h-5l-2 1-1 1-1 1 1 1v1l4 14 9 26 15-49h10l18 50 6-20 4-13 1-5 1-4-1-2-3-1-3-1h-4v-4h27z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="O_2" d="m663 49 5 7 2 10-2 10-5 8-9 5q-5 2-12 2l-10-2q-5-1-9-4l-5-8q-2-5-2-11l1-10q2-4 6-7 3-4 8-5l12-2q6 0 11 2 5 1 9 5zm-12 32 1-6 1-9-1-7-1-7-3-5-5-1-5 1-3 5-2 6v16q0 4 2 7l3 5 5 1 5-1 3-5z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="R" d="m723 52-2 6q-3 3-6 3-4 0-6-2t-2-5v-4l-4 1q-3 1-4 4v28l2 2 3 1h4v4h-32v-4h5l2-2V54l-1-3-1-2-3-1-2-1v-3l22-1h1v7q3-4 7-6 3-2 7-2 5 0 7 3 3 2 3 7z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="L_3" d="M755 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V29l-1-3-1-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="D" d="m820 89-23 1-1-1v-4l-7 4-8 2q-9 0-15-7t-6-18q0-10 7-17 6-7 16-7l7 1 6 2V29l-1-3-2-2-3-2h-5v-4l26-1v62l1 3 2 2 3 1h3zm-24-9V54l-1-3-2-2-2-2-4-1q-4 0-7 6-3 5-3 15v7l2 5 3 4 6 1 4-1 4-3z" />
    <path class="text-line" id="Z" d="M847 31v5l-2 7-2 10-3 15h-4l-2-15-3-10-1-7-1-5q0-4 3-7 2-2 6-2t7 2q2 3 2 7zm0 51q0 4-3 6-2 3-6 3-3 0-6-3-3-2-3-6 0-3 3-6l6-2q4 0 6 2 3 3 3 6z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699714/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Решение SMIL SVG

Реализуется поочередная прорисовка букв в фразе - **Hello World!** с помощью команды анимации изменения параметров `stroke-dashoffset` для каждой буквы:

```
 <animate id="an_H" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="519;0" dur="1s" 
 begin="svg1.click" restart="never" fill="freeze" > </path>
```

Для того чтобы эффект выглядел нормально, нужно точно вычислить максимальную длину линии:

```
<script>
console.log('length letter H :' + H.getTotalLength())
</script>
```

Для поочередной прорисовки букв используются логические цепочки в команде `begin`

Например для запуска анимации для  буквы `e` работает условие

`begin="an_H.end"`, -  анимация  буквы `е` начнется после окончания анимации `H`

*Анимация начинается после клика*

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.text-line {
fill: #2A4A73;
stroke:#2A4A73;
stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"   viewBox="0 0 1000 100" style="border:solid 1px #C1C4C7">
  <g  aria-label="Hell0 World!" style="line-height:13px;-inkscape-font-specification:'Georgia Bold'"  font-weight="700" font-stretch="normal" font-size="100" font-family="Georgia" >
    <g id="word" fill-opacity="0" >
          <!-- Анимация рисования буквы "H" -->
    <path class="text-line" id="H"  stroke-dasharray="519" stroke-dashoffset="519" d="M288 90h-36v-4h4l3-1 2-2 1-3V57h-29v23l1 3 2 2h3l4 1v4h-36v-4h3l4-1 2-2 1-3V33l-1-3-2-2-4-1h-3v-4h36v4h-3l-4 1-2 2-1 3v20h29V33l-1-3-2-2-3-1h-4v-4h36v4h-3l-4 1-2 2-1 3v47l1 3 2 2 4 1h3z" >
      <animate id="an_H" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="519;0" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click" restart="never" fill="freeze" > </path>   
          
    <path class="text-line" id="E" stroke-dasharray="279" stroke-dashoffset="279" d="m345 78-4 5-6 5-6 2-7 1q-7 0-12-2l-9-5-5-8-1-10q0-5 2-9 1-4 5-8l8-5q5-2 11-2l10 1q5 2 7 5 3 2 4 6l1 8v3h-31q0 9 3 14 4 5 12 5 5 0 8-2 4-2 6-6zm-18-17-1-6-1-5q0-2-2-3l-3-1q-4 0-6 3-2 4-2 12z" >
     <animate id="an_E" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  values="279;0" dur="0.5s" begin="an_H.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
       
    <path class="text-line" id="L_1" stroke-dasharray="217" stroke-dashoffset="217" d="M378 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V26l-2-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z">
      <animate id="an_L_1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="217;0" dur="0.4s" begin="an_E.end-0.2s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
    
    <path class="text-line" id="L_2" stroke-dasharray="217" stroke-dashoffset="217"  d="M411 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V26l-2-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z" >
       <animate id="an_L_2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="217;0" dur="0.4s" begin="an_L_1.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
    
    <path class="text-line" id="O_1" stroke-dasharray="289" stroke-dashoffset="289"  d="M468 46q4 4 5 9 2 4 2 9 0 7-2 12l-6 8-9 5q-5 2-12 2t-12-2q-6-2-9-6-4-3-6-8t-2-11l2-10 5-8q4-4 10-6 5-2 12-2 8 0 13 2t9 6zm-13 35 2-7V56l-2-8q-1-3-4-4-2-2-5-2t-5 2l-4 4-1 7-1 9v9l2 7q1 3 4 5 2 2 5 2t5-2q3-1 4-4z" >
       <animate id="an_O_1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="289;0" dur="1s" begin="an_L_2.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
    
    <path class="text-line" id="W" stroke-dasharray="572" stroke-dashoffset="572" d="m614 27-3 1-3 1-3 2-1 4-8 23-12 32h-9l-18-49-15 49h-10l-12-35-7-20-2-4-3-2-2-2h-4v-4h36v4h-5l-2 1-1 1-1 1 1 1v1l4 14 9 26 15-49h10l18 50 6-20 4-13 1-5 1-4-1-2-3-1-3-1h-4v-4h27z" >
      <animate id="an_W" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="572;0" dur="1s" begin="an_O_1.end-0.5s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
        
    <path class="text-line" id="O_2" stroke-dasharray="267" stroke-dashoffset="267" d="m663 49 5 7 2 10-2 10-5 8-9 5q-5 2-12 2l-10-2q-5-1-9-4l-5-8q-2-5-2-11l1-10q2-4 6-7 3-4 8-5l12-2q6 0 11 2 5 1 9 5zm-12 32 1-6 1-9-1-7-1-7-3-5-5-1-5 1-3 5-2 6v16q0 4 2 7l3 5 5 1 5-1 3-5z" >
      <animate id="an_O_2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="267;0" dur="1s" begin="an_W.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
        
    <path class="text-line" id="R" stroke-dasharray="231.5" stroke-dashoffset="231.5" d="m723 52-2 6q-3 3-6 3-4 0-6-2t-2-5v-4l-4 1q-3 1-4 4v28l2 2 3 1h4v4h-32v-4h5l2-2V54l-1-3-1-2-3-1-2-1v-3l22-1h1v7q3-4 7-6 3-2 7-2 5 0 7 3 3 2 3 7z" >
      <animate id="an_R" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="231.5;0" dur="0.5s" begin="an_O_2.end-0.2s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
      
    <path class="text-line" id="L_3" stroke-dasharray="216.3" stroke-dashoffset="216.3"  d="M755 90h-30v-4h5l2-2V29l-1-3-1-2-3-2h-4v-4l24-1 1 1v65l2 2 2 1h3z" > 
      <animate id="an_L_3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="216.3;0" dur="0.5s" begin="an_R.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
       
    <path class="text-line" id="D" stroke-dasharray="367" stroke-dashoffset="367" d="m820 89-23 1-1-1v-4l-7 4-8 2q-9 0-15-7t-6-18q0-10 7-17 6-7 16-7l7 1 6 2V29l-1-3-2-2-3-2h-5v-4l26-1v62l1 3 2 2 3 1h3zm-24-9V54l-1-3-2-2-2-2-4-1q-4 0-7 6-3 5-3 15v7l2 5 3 4 6 1 4-1 4-3z" >
      <animate id="an_D" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="367;0" dur="1s" begin="an_L_3.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
      
    <path class="text-line" id="Z" stroke-dasharray="163" stroke-dashoffset="163" d="M847 31v5l-2 7-2 10-3 15h-4l-2-15-3-10-1-7-1-5q0-4 3-7 2-2 6-2t7 2q2 3 2 7zm0 51q0 4-3 6-2 3-6 3-3 0-6-3-3-2-3-6 0-3 3-6l6-2q4 0 6 2 3 3 3 6z" > 
      <animate id="an_Z" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="163;0" dur="0.5s" begin="an_D.end-0.25s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /></path> 
     </g> 
           <!-- Анимация закраски букв -->
        <animate id="an_word" xlink:href="#word"  attributeName="fill-opacity" values="0.1;1" dur="1s" begin="an_Z.end" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" /> 
   </g>
   
</svg> 
</div>
<script>
console.log('length letter H :' + H.getTotalLength())
</script>
```

Comment: Я читал, но так и не понял что такое SMIL))) У меня отложилось, что он больше мертв чем жив...

Comment: @Leonid SMIL - [Все об SVG анимации](https://habr.com/ru/post/450924/) Жив пока. Что ты читал, наверняка относится к недавнему 5-ти летнему периоду, когда Chrome и другие иже с ним писали, что SMIL depricate() и скоро перестанут поддерживать его. Но потом разработчики chrome признались, что CSS анимации и web API по функционалу сильно уступают SMIL Поэтому пока смерть отложили и гадят потихоньку, что раньше работало в SMIL с новыми обновлениями Chrome перестаёт работать.

Comment: @Leonid Вот здесь я отвечал на EnSO на этот вопрос - [Is SMIL for SVG deprecated, un-deprecated or... paused but will eventually be deprecated] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558513/7394871)  А вот ссылка на [блог](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/5o0yiO440LM/m/YGEJBsjUAwAJ?pli=) Chromium, где они сказали что смерть SMIL откладывается, ввиду того, что нечем полноценно заменить

Comment: Я так понял, что SMIL спецификация была разработана для XHTML, переход на которую из HTML предполагался уже давно, но так и не случилось. Да и не реализовано это в браузерах для HTML. А SMIL в SVG - частный случай. И некоторый функционал для SVG реализован и понятно, что отменять его никто не собирается. То есть, SVG animations - SMIL лишь в той степени, сколько SVG - HTML )))) И получается, что в отдельном термине SMIL нет ни малейшего смысла. Ведь SMIL спецификация никогда не была воплощена в жизнь браузерами именно для HTML, но логика была перемещена в CSS-анимации. Или нет?

Comment: @Leonid ты по ссылкам не ходил? :) Всё не так. Это CSS сейчас начинает осваивать **некоторые возможности** анимации SMIL, который умеет это уже 25 лет. Повторюсь, поэтому отказались убивать smil, потому что пока не могут полноценно его заменить, так и пишут прямо разработчики Chrome, - это слишком сложно сделать :)

Comment: Как раз по ссылкам и ходил. Раньше я вообще утыкался только в статью на Википедии, где вообще о другом вроде, и в MDN, где указано как depricated. Просто я переше в саму спецификацию SMIL и там в "преамбуле" все сразу и написано))) По CSS я в том смысле, что реализация для HTML перекочевала туда, а с SVG это не связано. То есть, скажем для тега DIV же нельзя задать анимацию в стиле SMIL? Или можно? Но точно можно в CSS. А SVG в данном случае стоит особняком. Вот я про что...

Comment: @Leonid очень быстро читаешь :) такие объемные материалы. Кстати в одной из ссылок было написано, что Сара плохо знает материал по SMIL, а статьи пишет. Кстати есть перечень оф. атрибутов, которые можно применять и в CSS и в SMIL, но родом они из SMIL. такие как fill, stroke, stroke-dasharray. Но другие атрибуты smil, такие как `r`, `width`, path css совсем недавно начал внедрять. А насчет документации w3C я боюсь показаться критиканом, но в части SVG отвратительно написана документация, там и с бутылкой не разберешься.

Comment: @Leonid А вот читаешь документацию w3C по CSS, там всё чётко, понятно. Вот это одна из главных бед SVG - отсутствие нормальной документации и инструментария для разработки.

Comment: Это же рекомендация, своего рода предложение. А последнее слово за браузерами. И последняя рекомендация 2008 года, еще до того как основные производители браузеров начали активно сотрудничать с консорциумом и вырабатывать взвешенные решения, по сути обязательные для внедрения всеми участниками рынка. Это еще период "Голого поля" и "Дикого Запада" одновременно))) Сейчас уровень проработки любого документа совсем другой, как по детализации, так и по обязательности к реализации. Все несогласованные моменты сознательно остаются нерегламентированными.

Comment: @Leonid на мой взгляд война браузеров, только усилилась. Chrome поглощает один браузер, за другим и стал уже почти монополистом. Сам понимаешь какие беды бывают от монополизма. Из современных ему  противостоит только один FF, который наиболее правильно воспроизводит SVG, как раз выполняя требования спецификации.  А Chrome торопится, пытается обогнать спецификацию, называя это `экспериментальными технологиями` Вот и живем так, в одном браузере работает, в другом нет, вот и мучаемся в поисках компромиссного варианта

Comment: Если Edge в основе имеет Chromium, то это много лучше чем IE любой масти))) Если Яблоко само себя закопало с жесткой привязкой к железу, и не поспевает за критическими изменениями, то не удивительно, что они тоже суррогатят тот же Хромиум. С другой стороны уже есть Node.js на SpiderMonkey движке. И Мозилла пока еще сохраняет паритет с Гуглом. Каждый тянет на себя одеяло, да. Но вырабатывают стандарты более согласованно. Какие-то фишки включают - да. Но именно для экспериментов и последующего внедрения в стандарт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130842/discussion-between-leonid-and-alexandr-tt).